# Como faço para criar imagem circular com mascara css e efeito hover?

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Alguém sabe algum modelo de css pronto para eu usar como referência para recriar um efeito no meu site que estou passando de wordpress para html/css
Vi pelo código que é uma mascara de camada hover que cria o efeito, mas ainda não consegui reproduzir igual usando html/css.

São estes ícones que circulei de azul
Quero criar um efeito igual neste ícones usando apenas html/css
(quando o mouse passar em cima da imagem circular a mascara diminui e aumenta o tamanho da imagem, já quando o mouse não esta em cima da imagem ela aparece com uma mascara maior que faz com que ela pareça ser menor)

endereço dos sites são:

https://mdwebdesign.tk/
https://demo.presscustomizr.com/

as imagens são:

https://i.ibb.co/M6SxXqN/efeitohover.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/sJwfW3d/efeitohover2.jpg

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy cat]

Código:

html:

```
<main>
    <div class="linkshome">
        <div class="czr-link-mask">
            <a href="portfolio.html">
                <img src="img/portfolio.jpg">
                <h4>Portfólio</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="czr-link-mask">
            <a href="servicos.html">
                <img src="img/servicos.jpg">
                <h4>Serviços</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="czr-link-mask">
            <a href="contato.html">
                <img src="img/contato.jpg">
                <h4>Contato</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>     
</main>
```

css:

```
main {
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    padding: 20px;

}

.linkshome {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.linkshome h4{
    text-align: center;
}

/*Efeito Destaques (ainda testando efeitos para portfólio,serviços e contato.jpg)*/

.czr-link-mask-p.hover .czr-link-mask::before,.expanded .czr-link-mask::before, .czr-link-mask:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.4);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) scale(1.4);
    transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) scale(1.4);
}

/*Destaques*/
```

Comment: Coloque o que vc já tem de código ai, só o link do exemplo do link não ajuda a resolver o seu problema. Vc precisa fornecer o que já tem de modelo pronto ai pra podermos te dar uma solução pro seu caso.

Comment: Amigo, acho que vc não reparou, mas existe um botão escrito **EDITAR** logo abaixo do texto da sua pergunta. Vc deve clicar nele e incluir esses codigos todos direto dentro da sua pergunta, e não nos comentários aqui....

Comment: Cara dei uma formatada no código, mas para votarem para reabrir é preciso que vc edite também descrevendo esse efeito de hover que vc quer. Quem chegar agora e ler a pergunta só vai ver o código... cade a descrição do efeito que vc quer fazer? Agora sim vc pode deixar o código mais a explicação e o link do exemplo e tudo mais. Não encare como uma puxada de orelha, apenas estou te dando dicas para vc conseguir bolar suas perguntas dentro dos padrões do site. Abs

Comment: Ok Obrigado
Já editei a pergunta com o maior tipo de detalhes que lembrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Esse é apenas um exemplo, pode ter outras respostas com soluções diferentes. Basicamente para isso não existe uma única resposta...</sup>

A técnica que usei foi colocar a imagem dentro de uma `div`, pois não é possível usar pseudo-elemento direto na tag `img`. Então eu fiz o *pseudo elemento* na `div` que a imagem vai estar dentro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então nesse `::after` da `div` *container* da imagem eu usei um `box-shadow` para fazer a "mascara", no `:hover` e passo esse `box-shadow` para zero, com isso não preciso mexe na escala da imagem, e trabalho apenas como esse *pseudo elemento*... *O detalhe é que a cor do `box-shadow` tem que ser a mesma cor do fundo.*

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


main {
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  padding: 20px;

}

.linkshome {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.linkshome h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

/*Efeito Destaques (ainda testando efeitos para portfolio,serviços e contato.jpg)*/

.czr-link-mask {
  margin: 2rem;
}
.czr-link-mask .box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.czr-link-mask .box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: box-shadow 300ms;
}
.czr-link-mask a:hover .box::after{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px #fff;
}
.czr-link-mask .box img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

/*Destaques*/
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="linkshome">
    <div class="czr-link-mask">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        </div>
        <h4>Portfólio</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="czr-link-mask">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://placecage.com/101/100">
        </div>
        <h4>Serviços</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="czr-link-mask">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="https://placecage.com/100/101">
        </div>
        <h4>Contato</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

---

**Opção para cor sólida**

Quando a cor do box for sólida fica ainda mais fácil, pois vc pode trabalhas apenas no :hover do box, não precisa de classe para imagem ou pseudo elementos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
main {
   margin-left: 90px;
   margin-right: 60px;
   padding: 20px;

}

.linkshome {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.linkshome h4 {
   text-align: center;
}

/*Efeito Destaques (ainda testando efeitos para portfolio,serviços e contato.jpg)*/

.czr-link-mask {
   margin: 2rem;
}
.czr-link-mask .box {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 160px;
   height: 160px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: navy;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px navy;
   transition: box-shadow 300ms;
}
.czr-link-mask .box:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px navy;
}



/*Destaques*/
```

```html
<main>
   <div class="linkshome">
      <div class="czr-link-mask">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
         <div class="box">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icons-for-sharing-your-works/48/Behance_2.png">
         </div>
         <h4>Portfólio</h4>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="czr-link-mask">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
         <div class="box">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icons-for-sharing-your-works/48/Behance_2.png">
         </div>
         <h4>Serviços</h4>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="czr-link-mask">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
         <div class="box">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icons-for-sharing-your-works/48/Behance_2.png">
         </div>
         <h4>Contato</h4>
      </a>
      </div>
   </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Eu testei os dois exemplos, estão funcionado normal, mas quando apenas substituo as imagens para as que eu quero o efeito para de funcionar

Comment: @matheusdouradobr se funciona aqui deveria funcionar ai tb... A sua imagem funciona fora do exemplo? Ela carrega normalmente se estiver fora desse código ai?

Comment: Carrega sim, no segundo exemplo mudei as imagens para .png ai ja funcionou um pouco, já no primeiro exemplo nem em jpg nem em png funcionou, as imagens são estas:               
https://i.ibb.co/zr9rznS/contato.png
https://i.ibb.co/DrFsHJ7/servicos.png
https://i.ibb.co/DCZcS5k/portfolio.png
https://i.ibb.co/brh6M2C/contato.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/CJqddTS/servicos.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/fX5nySk/portfolio.jpg

Comment: @matheusdouradobr acho que pode ser problema de "crossbrowser" talvez... vc pode testar no Chrome na versão mais nova e ver se melhora...

Comment: @matheusdouradobr acho que já sei qual é o problama!! É que a sua imagem não vai até as bordas. Tipo olha no JPG, repara que o círculo com o ícone está no centro depois tem uma "borda" gigante até o final.... Vc tem que ajustar as suas imagens, elas tem que ser do tamanho total do arquivo e não ficar com esses espaços vazios... olha aqui http://prntscr.com/m83fj5

Comment: Ok Obrigado, vou testar aqui, acredito que vai dar certo agora, como voto como melhor resposta?

Comment: @matheusdouradobr teste ai e qualquer problema me fala. Para marcar a resposta como aceita basta clicar nesse ícone **`✔`** abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes mesmo já tendo sido resolvidas.

Comment: Ok agora acho que consegui votar como melhor resposta

Comment: @matheusdouradobr valeu jovem obrigado! 